# Can I indicate (via robots.txt, meta robots or another approach) that one or more queryString parameters should be ignored by crawlers?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers, robots.txt, query-string, meta-robots

I've written my own **SiteSearch** Script in PHP.

The **SiteSearch** parses two `GET` parameters from the `queryString`:

- `search` // *the search-phrase*
- `filters` (optional) // *indicating which parts of the site to include or ignore*

I don't mind **GoogleBot** and other crawlers reading the `search` parameter.

But I would like to advise crawlers to ignore the `filters` parameter, because a very high number of configurations of that parameter would simply return the same results - and an *identical, duplicate page* as far as the crawlers are concerned.

---

As much as I would like to add to my `robots.txt` file something like:

```
User-agent: *
IgnoreParameter: filters
```

this isn't an option.

And a meta robots directive like:

```
<meta name="robots" content="ignoreparams[filters]">
```

isn't an option either.

Is there any creative way I can enable crawling of the page *and* have crawlers ignore the `filters` parameter in the `queryString`?

Or am I stuck with a directive as unrefined as:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

if I don't want to risk pages with identical `search` parameters (but different `filters` parameters) being crawled?

Comment: You should disallow your entire site search in robots.txt.   Google will penalize your site if they find they are indexing your site search results pages.  They don't want to index your site search results because it is bad user experience for a user to leave the Google search results only to land on other search results.   See [Matt Cutts: Search results in search results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/).    You shouldn't be worrying about having crawlers ignore just one parameter, you should have crawlers ignore the entire site search.

Comment: Aha. Well, _that_ would make everything a lot easier! That Matt Cutts blog post is from March 2007, though... [1/2]

Comment: I wondered if anything might have changed in the last 14 years. I ran some searches and came across article from (only) just over a year ago (March 2020) by Barry Schwartz (aka _rustybrick_) at SE Roundtable: [Google: Indexing Search Result Pages Is A Watering Down Indexed Pages Issue](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-indexing-search-result-pages-29131.html) which references the original 2007 advice from Google, compares it with what was said in 2020 by John Mueller (in many ways Cutts' successor) and draws the same broad conclusion, albeit from a more nuanced perspective. [2/2]

Comment: What was bad user experience 14 years ago is still bad user experience today.   Google still doesn't want user clicking from their search results to other search results.

Comment: Google has doled out manual penalties for indexed site search.   They even sometimes put in a term like "viagra" and see if it has indexable site search results and then penalize for spam because of it.  They may have multiple motives, but it isn't worth risking your SEO by having Google crawl your site search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you should disallow your entire site search results.    However, there may be other pages for which you want to have search bots ignore some parameters.  There are two ways to get crawlers to ignore specific URL parameters:

### Robots.txt wildcards

Google and many other search engines support wild cards (`*`) in robots.txt rules.  You can use this functionality to disallow URLs that contain specific URL parameters:

```
Disallow: /path?*filter=
```

While the big search engines know how to interpret wildcards, most crawlers don't.  Rules with wildcards only work with some crawlers.

### Webmaster tools and search console settings

Google has a tool in search console called the [URL Parameters tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters).   Using this tool you could tell Google that the `filter` parameter "doesn't affect page content."

Comment: Thanks for shining a light on Google's **URL Parameters Tool**. It came up in my searches (on this page: [Taming Parameters by DeepCrawl.com](https://www.deepcrawl.com/blog/best-practice/taming-parameters/) ) alongside Bing's **Ignore URL Parameters Tool** (though I'm not sure the latter even exists anymore).

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended best practice to *disallow* indexing of **Site Search Pages**.

Note that while this *can* be done in `robots.txt`, using:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /search/
```

where `/search/` is the folder containing the **Site Search**.

**Yoast** recommends using `meta robots` instead:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
```

See:

> [...] blocking internal search pages via your `robots.txt` isn’t the
> best way to do this. It’s much better to allow search engines to crawl
> these kinds of pages, but to prevent them from indexing them by using
> a `meta robots` tag with a value of `noindex, follow`.
>
> **Source:** *https://yoast.com/blocking-your-sites-search-results/*

---

### Then and Now...

On **March 10th, 2007**, **Matt Cutts**, Head of Search Quality at **Google**, wrote:

> In general, we’ve seen that users usually don’t want to see search
> results [...] in their search results. [...] search results that don’t
> add much value already fall under our quality guidelines [...] so
> Google does take action to reduce the impact of those pages in our
> index.
>
> The new webmaster guideline that you’ll see on [... the quality
> guidelines page...] says “Use robots.txt to prevent crawling of search
> results pages or other auto-generated pages that don’t add much value
> for users coming from search engines.
>
> **Source:** *https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/*

On **March 10th, 2020**, **Barry Schwartz** of **Search Engine Roundtable** wrote:

> In 2007, Google told webmasters to block internal search results from
> being indexed. The original guideline read "Use robots.txt to prevent
> crawling of search results pages or other auto-generated pages that
> don’t add much value for users coming from search engines." Now it
> reads "Use the robots.txt file on your web server to manage your
> crawling budget by preventing crawling of infinite spaces such as
> search result pages."
>
> [...] Google's John Mueller explained why Google
> doesn't want your search result pages in its index. He said "they make
> infinite spaces (crawling), they're often low-quality pages, often
> lead to empty search results/soft-404s."
>
> So it really wasn't always about spam but blocking pages that might
> not be as relevant to Google.
>
> **Source:** *https://www.seroundtable.com/google-indexing-search-result-pages-29131.html*

---

**Further Reading:**

- Mar 2007: [Search Results in Search Results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/) (Matt Cutts at Google)
- Apr 2015: [Always Block Google from Accessing your Site's Search Results](https://www.labnol.org/internet/block-google-with-robots-txt/28861/) (labnol.org)
- Aug 2018: [Block Your Site’s Search Result Pages](https://yoast.com/blocking-your-sites-search-results/) (yoast.com)
- Mar 2020: [Google: Indexing Search Result Pages Waters Down Indexed Pages](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-indexing-search-result-pages-29131.html) (SE Roundtable)
- Mar 2020: [Should Internal Search Results Pages be Indexed?](https://www.practicalecommerce.com/should-internal-search-results-pages-be-indexed) (Practical eCommerce)
- Nov 2020: [Should Search Results Pages be Indexed? The Impact on SEO](https://www.goinflow.com/blog/should-internal-search-urls-be-indexed/) (GoInFlow)

Comment: Thanks, @StephenOstermiller - your quick answer in the comments above saved me potentially several hours of work this evening.